# HTML / CSS: Sidebar appears at bottom of page instead of on right side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening but I experiencing an issue where my sidebar isn't appearing as it should on the right hand side of the screen. I know I'm overlooking something simple but I've run through the code quite a few times and I can't seem to pinpoint what might be causing this.

Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/9e9X4/

HTML Code:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">

    <div id="content">
        <section id="main-content" role="main">

            <h2>BWL-T8-10-IXX-3000</h2>


            <!-- article -->
            <article id="post-131" class="post-131 page type-page status-publish hentry">
                <div class="entry-content">

                    <p><strong>Two Foot Linear T8 LED Tube</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p><strong>ELECTRICAL</strong>
                        <br />Input voltage: 100-277V
                        <br />Wattage: 10W</p>
                    <p><strong>OPTICAL</strong>
                        <br />Lamp Luminous Efficiency: &gt;110 lm/W
                        <br />Lumen Output: ~1100 lm
                        <br />Color temperature: 3000K
                        <br />Color rendering index: &gt;84
                        <br />Beam pattern: Circular
                        <br />Beam angle: 120 degrees
                        <br />Life spans: &gt;50,000 hours</p>
                    <p><strong>GENERAL</strong>
                        <br />Working temperature: -10C &#8211; 30C
                        <br />IP rating: IP40
                        <br />Product size: 26 x 600mm
                        <br />Net weight: 158.7g
                        <br />Warranty: 5 years</p>
                    <p><strong>Variants:</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>Non-Dimmable, Single-End Input:
                        <br />
                        <strong>BWL-T8-10-INS-3000</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>Dimmable, Single-End Input:
                        <br />
                        <strong>BWL-T8-10-IDS-3000</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>Non-Dimmable, Two-End Input:
                        <br />
                        <strong>BWL-T8-10-INT-3000</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>Dimmable, Two-End Input:
                        <br />
                        <strong>BWL-T8-10-IDT-3000</strong>
                    </p>

                </div>



                <br class="clear">

            </article>
            <!-- /article -->



        </section>
    </div>

    <!-- sidebar -->
    <aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">

        <div id="widget_sp_image-11" class="widget widget_sp_image">
            <h4>T8 Tube Lighting &#8211; 10 watt</h4>
            <img width="236" height="187" alt="T8 Tube Lighting &#8211; 10 watt" class="attachment-full alignleft" style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://brighterworldlightingllc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/t8-1.jpg" />
            <div class="widget_sp_image-description">
                <p><a class="button blue " href="tube-series/">T8 Tube Home</a>
                </p>
                <hr>
                <p>Additional options:
                    <br />
                    <a class="button blue " href="bwl-t8-10-ixx-3500/">Model BWL-T8-10-IXX-3500</a>
                </p>
                <p><a class="button blue " href="bwl-t8-10-ixx-5000/">Model BWL-T8-10-IXX-5000</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="widget_sp_image-24" class="widget widget_sp_image">
            <img width="300" height="73" alt="" class="attachment-medium" style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://brighterworldlightingllc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/41-320x78.jpg" />
        </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- /sidebar -->
</div>
<!-- END #content-wrapper -->
<footer id="footer">
    <div id="footer-inner" class="row">
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- END #footer -->
<div id="footer-bar">
    <div class="right">
        <div id="footer-nav">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        Copyright &copy; 2014 Brighter World Lighting. Powered by
        <a href="//wordpress.org" title="WordPress">WordPress</a> &amp; <a href="http://webtuts.pl/themes/corpo" title="Corpo Theme">Corpo Theme</a>.
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END #wrapper -->

<div style="display:none">
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://s0.wp.com/wp-content/js/devicepx-jetpack.js?ver=201414'></script>

<script src="http://stats.wordpress.com/e-201414.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    st_go({
        v: 'ext',
        j: '1:2.5',
        blog: '58938147',
        post: '131',
        tz: '0'
    });
    var load_cmc = function () {
        linktracker_init(58938147, 131, 2);
    };
    if (typeof addLoadEvent != 'undefined') addLoadEvent(load_cmc);
    else load_cmc();
</script>
</body>

</html>
<!-- Dynamic page generated in 0.707 seconds. -->
<!-- Cached page generated by WP-Super-Cache on 2014-04-06 05:15:23 -->

<!-- Compression = gzip -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to the `#sidebar` to be exactly on the right hand-side, along with the content, try:

```
#sidebar{    
    position:absolute;
    right:0;top:0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/9e9X4/1/)**

Or if you want it to be on the right side, below the main content, use:

```
#sidebar{    
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having your main content float left

```
#content { float:left }
```